# Running ipython remotely

Tags: python, tramp

I am trying to run an ipython interpreter remotely (with Emacs 24.5 and native `python.el`), but I'm not sure I have the right approach: whenever I try to run such a command for instance (which gets triggered with `C-c C-c`):

```
Run Python: /ssh:<server_name>:/usr/local/bin/ipython -i
```

(with `<server_name>` a valid entry in my `~/.ssh/config`, and `ipython` available at that remote location), I get an error like:

```
Warning (emacs): Python shell prompts cannot be detected.
If your emacs session hangs when starting python shells
recover with `keyboard-quit' and then try fixing the
interactive flag for your interpreter by adjusting the
`python-shell-interpreter-interactive-arg' or add regexps
matching shell prompts in the directory-local friendly vars:
  + `python-shell-prompt-regexp'
  + `python-shell-prompt-block-regexp'
  + `python-shell-prompt-output-regexp'
Or alternatively in:
  + `python-shell-prompt-input-regexps'
  + `python-shell-prompt-output-regexps'
```

as well as:

```
env: /ssh:<server_name>:/usr/local/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

in a `*Python*` buffer.. Is this making use of `tramp`, and is `python.el` able to run remote interpreters in such a way?

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use `*eshell*`.

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eshell`
- `cd /ssh:<server_name>:~`
- `run-python /usr/bin/ipython`
- Switch to `*Python*` buffer.

Comment: This is nice, but this doesnot make it possible to send code to the *Python* buffer. Is that correct?

Comment: @BakaKuna I solved that check my answer

Comment: amazing - this works over `/docker:<container>:` too

Answer (score 6):

@serv-inc answear is the best approach here:

> (setq python-shell-interpreter "ssh yourhost ipython"
>         python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")

but it will still fail with the error:

```
No such file or directory, ssh\
```

You must reference an executable on your path, so direct shell commands do not play, but writing a wrapper script will solve that, let's name it `remote-python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh hostname -t "ipython $@"
```

`-t` will force pseudo terminal allocation.

`$@` will delegate all the received arguments to the remote ipython.

This script must be in a directory which is defined in your `PATH` variable. You can check this inside Emacs with:

```
(getenv "PATH")
```

then you can set `remot-python` as your interpreter:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "remote-python"
            python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

If you get a warning about redline support:

```
(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
```

#### Note:

The beauty of this method, that it should work with almost every interpreter. I also tested it with julia-mode's REPL and You can write an interactive function to switch your remote/local interpreters.

Comment: Good to know that it helped a bit. Thanks

Comment: If emacs freezes when the remote python starts, remove everything in .basrc and try again

Answer (score -1):

Try evaluating (or even in `.emacs`)

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ssh yourhost ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")
```

and use like your local eval on any python file.

The first line sets the remote `ipython` as your default interpreter. The second line fixes an ipython problem.